# Disable mod_rewrite on index

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my mod_rewrite code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# ————————————————————————-
# > URL REWRITING
# ————————————————————————-

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/diario$ hotsite/diary.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/recados$ hotsite/messages.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/fotos$ hotsite/photos.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/videos$ hotsite/videos.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/contato$ hotsite/contact.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9._\-]+)$ hotsite/index.php [L]
```

It works just like facebook profiles. Whenever I type "mywebsite.com/user.name" it goes to that user page. I can also type "mywebsite.com/user.name/videos" to go to a specific page in the user profile.

However, I can't access "mywebsite.com" anymore, because it redirects to "mywebsite.com/hotsite/index.php". How can I disable this behavior and leave the redirects only when someone types a user name at the end?

Thank you very much.

Comment: To clarify a little better... the mod_rewrite thinks that anything I write after my domain url is a user name.
If I write "mywebsite.com/aboutUs" it thinks that "aboutUs" is a user name and redirects to /hotsite.
It redirects even when I write nothing like simply "mywebsite.com".

Comment: None of your rewrite rules are redirecting root i.e. "/". Can you check by turning `RewriteEngine off` if you're still getting redirected? If yes, problem is somewhere else, maybe another `.htaccess` or you may have a rule configured in `httpd.conf` <Directory> tags.

Comment: This is the rule causing the problem: RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9._\-]+)$ hotsite/index.php [L]. If I comment this rule, I can access "mywebsite.com" again. There are no other rules or .htaccess files.

Comment: Even for `http://mywebsite.com/`? ("/" url request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RewriteCondition`(s) only affect the `RewriteRule` that comes immediately after that. So, to stop redirecting `htp://mywebsite.com/aDirThatExists` like `http://mywebsite.com/aboutUs` you need to repeat the rewrite conditions as

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d    # if not a directory
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f    # and not a file
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9._\-]+)$ hotsite/index.php [L]
```

This, however, should not affect a root URL request i.e. `http://mywebsite.com/` because your regex clearly matches one or more characters after `/` because of the `[]+` plus sign.

Comment: @DanielFox Thanks for the appreciation. Did it work for `http://mywebsite.com/` as well?

Comment: You probably should add the [L] flag to the ends of the other lines also or you might get lines like `http://www.mysite.com/hotsite/index.php/videos.php` for it not stopping at the match.

Comment: @DanielFox Although, it would still work, it's a good idea to add `[NC,L]` flags to all of your other rewrite rules.

Comment: @Pjack Since , the `RewriteRule` regex doesn't include a `/` a double redirect like that won't happen. It's still a good practice to stop rewriting when done though and hence has been recommended to OP.

Comment: Yes, it worked for the root too Ravi Thapliyal! I added another rules later, like: RewriteRule ^about$ aboutUs.php, and it was redirecting to /hotsite because the of the previous rule, but then I put it BEFORE the rules mentioned above and now it's ok. Just in case someone has the same issue...